# how do I remove HTML element that I have created using Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, web

I have created HTML markup using Javascript now I want to remove that element when clicked, but its not working

```
      if (tBody) {
        return (
          `<tr class="tr1">  
    
    
            <th class="th1"> Category Name </th> 
            <th class="th1">Delete </th> 
    
    
        </tr>` +
          getdata.data
            .map(function (wizard) {
              return `<tr class="td1">  <td class=".th1"> ${wizard.categoryName}</td> 
                <td class="td1"><a class="delClass" onclick="removeCat()" data-remove="${JSON.stringify(wizard._id)}"   href="#">Delete</a></td>
                
                </tr>`;
            })
            .join('')
        );
```

Now I want to remove the above elements when clicked but I use `getElementsByClassName` and other methods but its not working

Error message and code images[image]

[image]

[image]

new images**********

[image]
enter image description here

[image]

the html is rendered dynamically

here is the picture

[image]

data-remove image here********[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) to find the `tr` and remove it:

```js
function removeCat(e) {
    e.closest('tr').remove()
};
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td><button onclick="removeCat(this)">-</button>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>2</td>
  <td><button onclick="removeCat(this)">-</button>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>3</td>
  <td><button onclick="removeCat(this)">-</button>
</tr>
</table>
```

Beside, I see your delete buttons has class `delClass` so you can add event listener to this class and avoid inline script. For example:

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("delClass");

var removeCat = function() {
    console.log(this.dataset.remove)
    this.closest('tr').remove();
};

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].addEventListener('click', removeCat, false);
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td><button class="delClass" data-remove="1">-</button>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>2</td>
  <td><button class="delClass" data-remove="2">-</button>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>3</td>
  <td><button class="delClass" data-remove="3">-</button>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks alot i really appreciate  it , also now i have another problem is that  the data that i delete is just on front end as soon as i refresh the page it will show again , how do i pass _id of category  in removeCat function , i tried wizard._id but its not working , im using mongoose.

Comment: You can use `this.dataset.remove` (or `e.dataset.remove` if you follow the first solution) to get it

Comment: ,i tried pasing the id like removeCat(this,${wizard._id}) but its not working, after ai get id am goona send a get request through axios and delete it from mongoose as well

Comment: bro  i need to pass the id server side and then using mongoose schema ,like categorySchema.findOneanddelete({_id:req.body._id}).then.... and delete , how is this.dataset.remove it from database?

Comment: I mean you can get id with `let id = this.dataset.remove` and pass it to the request.

Comment: oh  i understand now ,  btw thanks alot for your time  and help , really appreciate  your help :)

Comment: i tried to get it  but its not working -->  in removeCat function i  used                            
  let data= this,dataset.remove   but its not woring  ,, error is Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined

Comment: If you use the second solution, it should be `this` instead of `e`

Comment: ,please can u provide a solution , i am  facing difficulty this.dataset.remove  gives error remove is not defined ?

Comment: i have provided three images kindly take a look at them , it still not working ..

Comment: did you remove the inline script at `onclick=...`?

Comment: im really sorry i new to this , i couldn't  understand , can u please elaborate your answer?

Comment: Because you added event listener to `delClass` so you don't need inline script anymore. And in inline script function, `this` is window so it doesn't have `dataset`, that's why you need to remove it

Comment: okay right , how do i make this work , how do i get the datset.remove   ?

Comment: Just remove `onclick="removeCat()"` and follow the second solution.

Comment: i removed the onclick but now the event listener dont work , please take a look at new images****

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232074/discussion-between-cuong-le-ngoc-and-afnan).

Answer (score 0):

You use a query selector and the `remove` method:

```js
tBody.querySelectorAll('tr').forEach(tr => tr.remove());
```

Or if your table has other rows you don't want to delete, then you must have a way of targeting those exactly. Either give them some special `class`, or maybe you can use the ones you've already given:

```js
tBody.querySelectorAll('.tr1, .td1').forEach(tr => tr.remove());
```